# I want a button that will open my document in another browser tab

Tags: javascript, python

I am filling a document with expense information dynamically, I have created a button that shows that information as a pdf, the problem is that it only works once, if I want to return to the page and press the button again, it no longer works. So I have decided that the button opens the pdf in another tab, but I have problems.
This is the original code... Any help would be great

```js
function get_preview_data(frm) {
    frappe.call({
        method: "erpnext.hr.doctype.expense_claim.expense_claim.get_expense_data",
        args: {
            name: frm.doc.name,
        },
        async: false,
        callback: function (r) {
            let data = r.message; // data recibida desde .py
            console.log(data);
            console.log(frm.doc);

      //Creo las condiciones para que se llene el documento con sus datos4
       ........
      // Fin de llamada de datos
      
      //Asigno ruta con la que se va abrir el documento
            frappe.set_route("ride-expense-claim",
                frm.doc.company,
                environment,
                frm.doc.emission_type,
                frm.doc.authorization_number,
                company_tax_id,
                keep_account,
                main_address,
                frm.doc.establishment_address,
                htmlPayMeth,
                frm.doc.employee_name,
                employee_id,
                employee_addr,
                frm.doc.posting_date,
                frm.doc.fecha_autorizacion,
                number,
                htmlRepayment,
                htmlExpDetail,
                htmlTotalValues,
                total_reembolso
            )
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola! Estás en stackoverflow en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta o borrala y pregunta en el sitio en inglés.

Comment: Hola, estás en StackOverflow en Castellano

Comment: Hola! Estas usando StackOverflow en Español, no StackOverflow en Inglés

Comment: @Marcos-MD tu edición fue rechazada porque es el OP (autor de la publicación) quien debe traducirla. Podés revisar en [meta] por qué cualquier usuario no puede traducir una pregunta.